# What is the Preferred Mathematical Representation for a Forward Pass in a Neural Network?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I know this may be a question of semantics but I always see different articles explain forward pass slightly different. e.g. Sometimes they represent a forward pass to a hidden layer in a standard neural network as `np.dot(x, W)` and sometimes I see it as `np.dot(W.T, x)` and sometimes `np.dot(W, x)`.

Take this image for example. They represent the input data as a matrix of `[NxD]` and weight data as `[DxH]` where H is the number of neurons in the hidden layer. This seems the most natural since input data will often be in tabular format with rows as samples and columns as features.

[image: Example]

Now an example from the CS231n course notes. They talk about this below example and cite the code used to compute it as:

```
f = lambda x: 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x)) # activation function (use sigmoid)
x = np.random.randn(3, 1) # random input vector of three numbers (3x1)
h1 = f(np.dot(W1, x) + b1) # calculate first hidden layer activations (4x1)
h2 = f(np.dot(W2, h1) + b2) # calculate second hidden layer activations (4x1)
out = np.dot(W3, h2) + b3 # output neuron (1x1)
```

Where `W` is `[4x3]` and x is `[3x1]`. I would expect the weight matrix to have dimensions equal to [n_features, n_hidden_neurons] but in this example it just seems like they transposed it naturally before it was used.

[image: Example2]

I guess I am just confused about general nomenclature in how data should be shaped and used consistently when computing neural network forward passes. Sometimes I see transpose, sometimes I don't. Is there a standard, preferred way to represent data in accordance to a diagram like these This question may be silly but I just wanted to discuss it a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;**

*NumPy handles the computation for dot product of 2 arrays without worrying too much about the order in which they are added to parameters IF one or both of them are 1-D arrays. In case of 2-D arrays, the dot product requires them to share the last and first axis respectively.*

---

**Detailed explanation;**

From a mathematical point of view, during dot product `(nxm)` and `(mx1)` should share a common dimension so that the resultant array is of the form `(nx1)`. However, from an implementation perspective, numpy handles the shapes of inputs if one or both of them are 1-D arrays. As per [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

> - If both `a` and `b` are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors
>   (without complex conjugation).
> - If both `a` and `b` are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication,
>   but using :func:`matmul` or `a @ b` is preferred.
> - If either `a` or `b` is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to :func:`multiply`
>   and using `numpy.multiply(a, b)` or `a * b` is preferred.
> - **If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is a 1-D array, it is a sum-product over the last axis of `a` and `b`**.
> - If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is an M-D array (where `M>=2`), it is a
>   sum-product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last axis of `b`

Therefore, consider the toy example -

```
x = np.array([4,5,6]) #shape - (3,1)
W = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]) #shape - (3,3)

np.dot(x, W)
#Output - array([4, 5, 6])

np.dot(W.T, x)
#Output - array([4, 5, 6])

np.dot(W, x)
#Output - array([4, 5, 6])
```

All of the above have the same result computationally because the last axis of both W and x is 3 , which is shared while the other axes result in the dot product which can be either (1,3) or (3,1) which NumPy simplifies to a (3,) changing it to a 1-D vector instead of a 2-D matrix with a single row.

> - **If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum-product over the last axis of a and b.**

This doesn't work as easily when we are taking dot product of 2-D arrays. This is where you have to make sure that the first array shares its last axis with the first axis of the second array. example -

```
W2 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]) #shape - (2,3)

np.dot(W, W2)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-913-839ef1feb8c0> in <module>
----> 1 np.dot(W, W2)

ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```